# How to make Color Picker VSCode extension not block polish letter Ć?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I can't type Ć in VSCode, which is a regular character in polish language, NOT an accented character.
Normally I type it by pressing option + C, but in VSCode this results in a message on the bottom of window:

```
Waiting for second key of chord...
```

I have unchecked Allow Chords in settings, but it still appears. There is also no keybinding for option + c.

Other polish characters are entered without problems, eg. Ś (option + S).

EDIT: I figured out that Color Picker extension causes the problem, but still I don't know how to fix it (I want to keep this plugin;)

Comment: Yes, I didn't find an answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press and hold C button. On my mac book its working. You hold and mac will suggest you to choose letter C

Comment: OK this is a solution. Not the most comfortable, but maybe I'll stick to it. BTW I edited the question with new info.